# Converting an image into a HTML email signature with buttons

Tags: html, css, outlook

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQFcK.jpg

I am trying to create an email signature for outlook at have created the design linked above (I have censored all of the text). I want to convert the image into a html document so that I can add buttons onto the image and then put the html code into outlook for the signature. All of the censored information on the right should have its own individual button plus the two censored bits at the bottom and the 4 social media links (9 total buttons).

I have started making something but it doesn’t work and I don’t know if I am even going in the right direction. Please can I get some help with this? Am I even doing the right thing? Please see code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
<!--link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet type="text"/-->
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}
 
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
 
.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 6%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58.9%;
  left: 12%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btn2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58.9%;
  left: 16%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btn3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58.9%;
  left: 20%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btn4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58.9%;
  left: 24%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btna {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 12%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btne {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 12%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btnp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 12%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btnl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 12%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.container .btnw {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  left: 12%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
 
</head>
 
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img src = "C:\Users\RhysPayne\Flourish PR Limited\FlourishTeam - Documents\Flourish Staff Folders\Rhys Payne/Email Signature - Card 1.jpg"/>
  <button class="btn" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btn1" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btn2" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btn3" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btn4" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btna" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btne" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btnp" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btnl" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
<button class="btnw" onclick="alert('Hello world!')"> </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rhys

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I help you. Please follow this code. Or send me your design sample. Thanks

```html
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');
</style>
<table width="360" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border-spacing='0' style="width: 360px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; border-collapse:collapse; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
        <tr>
            <td width="360" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border-spacing='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="130" valign="middle" style="text-align:left;">
                            <a href="https://www.pmaclermont.com/" target="_blank"><img moz-do-not-send="true" border="0" width="120" height="78" src="https://i.ibb.co/TqdX2r3/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td width="230" style="padding-left: 15px; border-left:1px solid #20ae4b;">
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="220" style="padding-bottom:8px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <p style="margin: 0;">
                                            <span style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: #20ae4b; font-weight:bold;">Clay Brian | </span><span style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: #000000;">Owner</span>
                                        </p>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="230" style="padding-bottom:8px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <p style="margin: 0;">
                                            <span style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt;  color: #2f455c;"> Rainbows and Butterflies, Inc.<br>d/b/a Premier Martial Arts- Clermont, FL</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="230" style="font-size:9pt;">
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="230" style="line-height:14pt;">
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    <p style="margin:0;">
                                                        <img moz-do-not-send="true" border="0" width="13" height="13" src="https://i.ibb.co/7bkdnfP/cell.png" alt="cell" style="vertical-align:middle;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="tel:4074530644" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; color: #2f455c; text-decoration: none;">(407) 453-0644</a>
                                                    </p>
                                                    
                                                    <p style="margin:0;">
                                                        <img moz-do-not-send="true" border="0" width="13" height="13" src="https://i.ibb.co/Rpm1Wcy/website.png" alt="website" style="vertical-align:middle;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.pmaclermont.com/" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; color: #2f455c; text-decoration: none;">www.pmaclermont.com</a>
                                                    </p>
                                                    
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td width="230" valign="bottom" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:left; padding-top: 7px;">
                                                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/pmaclermont/" target="_blank"><img moz-do-not-send="true" border="0" width="22" height="22" src="https://i.ibb.co/F8Vc4n0/instagram.png" alt="instagram"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://facebook.com/premiermartialartsclermont" target="_blank"><img moz-do-not-send="true" border="0" width="22" height="22" src="https://i.ibb.co/D7TRtFw/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
                                                </td> 
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```